# Get global UTC timestamp across all platforms

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, utc

I am trying to get the current timestamp for my program on both the client side, and the server side in python. However, my friends, along with myself, have problems. I have tried syncing both times, and tries numerous different methods to get the current time as UTC that is globally synced.

Here is what I've tried, with an invalid outcome.

1. ```
   import datetime
   datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp()
   ```
2. ```
   import arrow
   arrow.now().timestamp()
   ```
3. ```
   import time
   time.time()
   ```
4. ```
   from datetime import datetime, timedelta
   import time
   unixtime = time.mktime(datetime.now())
   ```
5. ```
   from datetime import datetime
   import calendar
   d = datetime.utcnow()
   unixtime = calendar.timegm(d.utctimetuple())
   ```

Along with countless more methods.

Comment: `time.time()` should return the same value for *every* system. Your clock is probably broken. What do you need both timestamps for?

Comment: My auth system will be sending the timestamp of the request, to make sure that it was not tampered with, and if the program returns the same response with an invalid timestamp, It would exit the program. @EricJin Do you know how I would sync my clock? It is a windows system.

Comment: I'm not sure, but there might be guides online for that. You should also check https://time.gov to see how inaccurate your clock is.

Comment: It is very unlikely that both sides would ever obtain precisely the same time due to varying amount of latency on each system due to hardware, software, and other differences.

Comment: Use `time.time()`. Or `datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).timestamp()` (basically the same thing). Or query an NTP server if you need a reference.